# How to update a single field in has_many object

Tags: activerecord, ruby-1.9.2

I am having a user object which has one-to-many relation with Address object. My class looks like this

```
class User
  has_many :address
end

class Address
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I want to update only city column in address table for a particular user.
How to do this?

I tried like this

```
@user.address.each do |a|
  a.city = 'Alabama'
end
@user.save
```

But this is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a.update_attributes(:city => 'Alabama')
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work.

```
@user.address.update_all(:city => 'Albama')
```